# In meteor js ,In edit form i'm unable to display the dropdown box values which i stored during adding a form

Tags: mongodb, meteor

> I have a form that uses drop-down boxes to save information in mongo
>   Db. That works fine, but the problem comes when I am trying to edit
>   the information in the database.I used the same form (add form) to
>   edit the information. it pulls the values from the database and
>   displays the fields in the fields accordingly. However, I am having a
>   hard time figuring out how to populate the drop-down boxes with the
>   value from the database. Basically, I want the "option selected" tag
>   to be the database and be able to still have the rest of the options
>   to select from.in text box I am getting the text values from database
>   but in drop down I wont be able to get the value.

```
       addmenu.html
    <template name="addMenu">
      <form class="addingMenus">
        <p><input type="text" name="menuName" id="menuName" placeholder="Choose Label" value = {{menuName}}></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="associatedPages" id="associatedPages" placeholder="Enter Associated Pages" value= {{associatedPages}}></p>
        <p><input type="text" name="menuUrl" id="menuUrl" placeholder="Enter Page URl" value={{menuUrl}}></p>
        <p>
          <select id="level" >
            <option name="parent"  value="0" selected = {{rejected}}>parent level</option>
            <option name="child" value="1" selected = {{accepted}}>child level</option>
          </select>

          <select id="childLevel" style="visibility:hidden">
            {{#each parent}}
            <option value = "{{this._id}}" selected = {{subMenu}} >{{this.menuName}}</option>
            {{/each}}
          </select>
        </p> 
        <p>
          <select id="publishStatus">
            <option name="publish" value="true" selected="{{published}}">publish</option>
            <option name="unpublish" value="false" selected="{{unpublished}}">unpublish</option>
          </select>
        </p>
        <p><button type="button"  class="save-button" id="{{task}}-save-button">SAVE</button></p>
      </form>
    </template>



    addmenu.js:



    Template.addMenu.events({
      'click #add-menu-save-button': function (event,template) {
        //event.preventDefault();
        console.log(event);
        var levelId = document.getElementById('level').value;
        if (levelId == 1) {
          parentId = document.getElementById('childLevel').value; 
        } else {
          parentId = "null";
        } 
        var publishStatus = document.getElementById('publishStatus').value;
        //console.log(publishStatus);
        let menuInsert = {
          menuName: document.getElementById('menuName').value,
          associatedPages: document.getElementById('associatedPages').value,
          menuUrl: document.getElementById('menuUrl').value,
          level: document.getElementById('level').value,
          createdAt: new Date(),
          publishStatus: publishStatus,
          parentId: parentId
        };
        Meteor.call("addMenu", menuInsert, function (error, result) {
          if(error) {
            console.log("error in adding a menu");
          } else {
            alert("successfully entered in database");
            Router.go('/administrator/admin');
          } 
        }); 
      },
      'click #level': function (event, template) {
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log(document.getElementById('level').value);
        if(document.getElementById('level').value == '1') {
          document.getElementById("childLevel").style.visibility = "visible";
          console.log("iam in session in level");
        } else {
          document.getElementById("childLevel").style.visibility = "hidden";
        }
      }
    });



    Template.addMenu.helpers({
      parent: function () {
        return menuDetails.find({level: "0"});
      },
      accepted: function (event) {
        console.log(this.level);
        if(this.level == "1") {
          Session.set('submenu',this.parentId);
          console.log(Session.get('submenu'));
          return "selected";
        }
      },
      rejected: function (event) {
        if(this.level == "0") {
          return "selected";
        }
      },
      subMenu: function (event) {
        var id = Session.get('submenu');
        console.log(this._id);
        if(id == this._id) {
          return "selected";
        }
      },
      published: function (event) {
        if(this.publishStatus == true) 
          return "selected";
      },
      unpublished: function (event) {
        if(this.publishStatus == false) 
          return "selected";
      }
    });
```

Comment: you will need a helper function to check the rendered option equaling to the saved data or not. If equal, then return `selected` on the `option` of the `select`

Comment: .when i click on the edit button iam calling a router and in that iam setting data content based on the id .and iam sending the data to the edit menu template and calling the edit menu.in edit menu iam including addmenu template.here iam not getting where to call helper function to get display data in the dropdown.

Comment: Thanku @Thai Tran  :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify your template like this.

```
<select id="childLevel" style="visibility:hidden">

{{#each parent}}
    <option {{isSelected this.menuName}} value = "{{this._id}}">{{this.menuName}}</option>
{{/each}}

</select>
```

then in the helper you need to write this custom helper.

```
Template.addMenu.helpers({
isSelected: function(menuName){
   return (menuName == 'your conditional value here') ? 'selected': '';
}
});
```

Comment: You forgot to return it :)

Comment: Thanku Ahmed :) . but here i have two dropdown boxes.the first one is "select level" and whenever we select the child level another dropdown will appear(which contains parent name). in my database the values are like "_id" : "v9rF3zChMHhHiKh5n",
    "menuName" : "Partners",
    "menuUrl" : "partners123",
    "level" : "1",
    "associatedPages" : "partners",
    "createdAt" : ISODate("2016-02-11T03:59:30.948Z"),
    "publishStatus" : true,
    "parentId" : "45wynxrPYTg7jjyP7"

Comment: during editing the existing page iam retrieving values from db .but iam not getting how to put the db values in <select> tag.from the above values i want to result like . the first dropdown should contain "child level" as a selected and the second dropdown should contain the name of parent (Home i.e based on parent id "45wynxrPYTg7jjyP7".

Comment: Thanku Faysal Ahmed .i created helper for each option in select tag and compared with the database values and i return "selected" value.nw iam able to get the values in dropdown box .thank u very much :)